# change DirectoryIndex file for subdomain

Tags: htaccess

I want two languages on my website - one french-specific website, and one in english for broader purposes (and no automatic translation).
For maintenance reasons, I'd like to not duplicate images and CSS, ... I also set up subdomains for language variants - for now both point to the www folder of my domain.

So I have two "index.htm" and "index_fr.htm" files, and a "fr" subdomain.

I've read up a bit about htaccess, and I'd like to set one up so that `DirectoryIndex index_fr.htm` is triggered when accessed through the subdomain.

Is it feasible? does it make sense? and how?

Comment: Where is the `DocumentRoot` set for the subdomain?  Is it served out of its own directory or out of the same?

Comment: I'm a noob for this kind of stuff so please bear with me :/
First, it is not my own server, it is a webhosting (OVH). So the urls are already redirects. Both the www subdomain and the fr subdomain point to the www folder. So I'd say the DocumentRoot is the www folder. If you refer to a specific file called DocumentRoot, no idea where it is and I'd think it is not accessible by me.

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is an Apache directive (and so is `DirectoryIndex`).    `DocumentRoot` controls which directory serves the files for a virtual host (usually a domain or subdomain).   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot   On shared hosting you may not have a lot of control over that.   It is common to have subdomains point to subfolders of the main `DocumentRoot` and that comes with its own set of problems.  It sounds like your host set the `DocumentRoot` to the same directory for both your main domain and subdomain.  Do you know if you can change that?

Comment: I can. I set up the subdomain, and in doing so I chose the directory it points to. 
At first I tried having it pointing to a `fr/` subfolder (with index.htm in french in it), but then it couldn't read my css which was then one level above...

Comment: to keep it simple, what I want is more like a hidden redirect of the subdomain url to that particular html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see as you necessarily need to change the `DocumentRoot` of the subdomain (as discussed in comments), since you want to "share images and CSS" between language versions.

However, changing the `DirectoryIndex` is probably not what you want to do either.

Instead, use mod_rewrite to internally rewrite the request to `/index_fr.htm` when requesting the document root of the subdomain.

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fr\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index_fr.htm [L]
```

This is essentially the equivalent of conditionally setting `DirectoryIndex`.

If you request `https://fr.example.com/` then you'll be internally redirected to `/index_fr.htm`. Otherwise the normal `DirectroryIndex` will be served.

However, it's not clear how you want to handle requests of the form `https://fr.example.com/foo`? The above directive does not cover that.

Comment: perfect, thank you! for your question, I haven't thought about that...because it's a single-page website, and instead of having `fr.example.com/foo` I have `fr.example.com#foo` so it works :)